# How to remove a list from a nested list in python?

Tags: python, nested-loops, probability, combinatorics

I'm exploring probability with the use of python and I want to resolve this kind of problem. I have 5 couples and from these couples, I want to extract each group of three, that doesn't contain persons from a married couple.

```
import itertools as it

married_couples = [["Mary","John"],["Homer","Marge"],["Beauty","Beast"],["Abigail","George"],["Marco","Luisa"]]

all_persons = []
for couples in married_couples:
    for person in couples:
        all_persons.append(person)

sample_space = list(it.combinations(all_persons,3))

# Better solution with generator:
sample_space = [s for t in it.combinations(married_couples, 3) for s in it.product(*t)]
```

Now I would like to proceed excluding from the sample space all results that contains people from the same married couple and I try:

```
correct_results = sample_space.copy()
for couple in married_couples:
    for res in sample_space:
        if couple[0] in res and couple[1] in res:
                if res in correct_results:
                    correct_results.remove(res)
```

Edit: I edited and put also the generator solution inside, so you can use this code for the purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

```
if couple[0] and couple[1] in res:
```

because it tests not that the couple is in `res`, but that the first element of the couple is not null and the second is in `res`.

You should use:

```
if couple[0] in res and couple[1] in res:
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much more efficient way to do this:

```
r = [s for t in itertools.combinations(married_couples, 3) for s in itertools.product(*t)]
```

If you just need to iterate over this, and don't need it as an actual expanded list, then you can instead create a generator:

```
iter = (s for t in itertools.combinations(married_couples, 3) for s in itertools.product(*t))
```

Then you can do:

```
for triple in iter:
    ...
```

Both solutions work as follows:  There are two levels to it. At the top level, it calls `itertools.combinations(married_couples, 3)`. This generates all triplets from the original set of married couples. Then, for each triplet, it uses `iterrools.product(*t)` to generate all 8 combinations that take one from each of the three pairs in the triplet.

Comment: My problems concerning iterators is always the readability and to let also extern people understand what is the goal, but maybe I cannot follow because I'm a beginner.

Comment: They look almost identical.  The list uses `[]`, and the generator uses `()`.  The difference is the list allocates memory for every single combination up front, while the generator creates them on the fly as needed.  But if it's small enough and you want the full list, just use the first form.  They're both equally concise, and more efficient that the approach in the posted question.

Comment: I am starting my journey with python and probabilities and I wanted to transpose in python typical probability problems. I'm sure your solution is much better, but could you please explain to me logically how it works? Sorry now I understand! You are substituing my:                                                                                                   all_persons = []
for couples in married_couples:
    for person in couples:
        all_persons.append(person)

Comment: Update:  The original code I posted wasn't quite right.  It was generating nested lists rather than a single flat list of triples.  It's fixed now, so grab a fresh copy if you're using it.

Comment: To answer your question:  There are two levels to it.  At the top level, it calls `itertools.combinations(married_couples, 3)`.  This generates all triplets from the original set of married couples.  Then, for each triplet, it uses `iterrools.product(*t)` to generate all 8 combinations that take one from each of the three pairs in the triplet.